# Using MVC5's RoutePrefix with areas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I currently have a controller which is located at /account/signin. How can I use MVC5's RoutePrefix to make it addressable at /account/sign-in?

I've tried decorating my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("account/sign-in")]
public class SignInController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and mapping my routes in `RegisterRoutes`:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

but I get this exception when doing so:

> The controller for path '/account/sign-in' was not found or does not implement IController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted my default routing file (`AccountAreaRegistration.cs`) and it's now working. I didn't realise you can't use both!

Answer (score 1):

You can also add:

```
context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

to the `RegisterArea` method in your `AccountAreaRegistration` class, and then use something like:

```
[RouteArea("admin")]
[RoutePrefix("menu")]
[Route("{action=index}/{id?}")]
```

At the top of your controller, use attribute routing for one or more controllers in your area and leave the rest using the default you set up; e.g.,

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin",
            url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { area = "Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Then you have both.